# jcombobox using it with a jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am wondering how i can set up a JComboBox that works with a Jbutton. Having a certain object selected in the JcomboBox changes the calculation when the button is pressed. This is what i have so far but it doesnt seem to work and im not sure what is wrong with it.

```
    //JComboBox objectList = new JComboBox();
    String[] objectStrings = { "Triangle", "Box", "Done" };
    JComboBox objectList = new JComboBox(objectStrings);
    //objectList.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Triangle", "Box", "Done"}));
    objectList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    final int object = objectList.getSelectedIndex();
    objectList.setBounds(180, 7, 86, 20);
    objectList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (object == 2) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });



    frmPrestonPalecekWeek.getContentPane().add(objectList);

    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate!");
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String box;
            String done;
            Box a;
            Triangle b;
            b = new Triangle(Double.parseDouble(txtSidea.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtSideb.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtSidec.getText()));
            a = new Box(Double.parseDouble(txtSidea.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtSideb.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtSidec.getText()));
            if (object  == 0) {
            txtOutput.setText("this is the volume " + a.getVolume());
            }
            else if (object == 2) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In button's action listener you should check for the item selected in the combo box, rather than using the index that was set up during initialization (`final int object = objectList.getSelectedIndex()`) as it is not going to change when combo selection is changed. This variable is even marked as `final`.

For example you could do something similar:

```
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       int selectedIndex = objectList.getSelectedIndex();
       if (selectedIndex == 0) {
           ...
       } else if selectedIndex == 2) {
          ...       
       }
    }
}
```